# To get children value before child in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's my structure of database for storing the latitude, longitude and subject under username. Now i am the current user of slocation and I want to find the same subject as my subject in tlocation user. I know for loop can find the same subject but if detect the same subject then how do i get the username of the same subject?
Please advice me if my thinking insertion to database got error. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a query to get the nodes from `tlocation`.

```
String subject = "P - mathematics";
DatabaseReference tlocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tlocation");
Query subjectQuery = tLocatinRef.orderByChild("subject").equalTo(subject);
subjectQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
})
```

Also see:

- [Listen for Value events for a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)
- [Listen for Child* events for a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events)
- [Sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Comment: Thank you. If got problem then I get back to you